# Symfony set Field name when schema fields have spaces

Tags: symfony1, schema, propel

We have a Excel spreadsheet with data to import into MySQL from a client. Some of the column names have spaces in them, so when we build the schema with the *data-dump* function it adds spaces into the field names; thus the BaseModels have it too.

```
'Client Field': { type: string, peerName: client_field }
```

Wondering if there is an attribute to add to the field in the schema to add spaces to the field names? For example there is **peerName** and **phpName**: is there an attribute to remove the spaces from fields?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean (and having spaces in the field name is a bad design), but this might be what you want:

```
class YourModel extends BaseYourModel
{
    public function setClientField($value)
    {
        return parent::_set('Client Field', $value);
    }
    public function getClientField()
    {
        return parent::_get('Client Field');
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that the BaseYourModel classes don't underscore the protected variable names. Thus, the class is incorrect, and when we run the task it fails.

Comment: Also aware that the spaces is bad design.